# Loading data files with ShinyFiles

Tags: r, shiny

I have several data files that my Shiny app is supposed to load. To achieve this, I try to use the [`ShinyFiles` package](https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles). From `ui.R`:

`shinyFilesButton('file', 'Load Dataset', 'Please select a dataset', FALSE)`

However, I am unsure about what to put in `server.R` to load the file. I know how to get the file path and all, but where do I put the `load()` command?

This is what I try now: (from `server.R`):

```
observeEvent(input$file, {
 inFile <- parseFilePaths(roots=roots, input$file)
 load(as.character(inFile$datapath), envir=.GlobalEnv)
})
```

The files are data files as saved by `save.image()` and contains some data frames, matrices and lists produced by another R script. In my Shiny app, I want to use the data mainly for graphics, so I need them to get loaded while the app is running.

Comment: Do i need to pass something different to `envir`? Using `envir=.GlobalEnv`, the file seems to load, but Shiny seems not to use the contents until I quit the app and restart it.

Comment: show something reproduceble to test. It s hard to answer when dont know what in your files. and how you wnat to load it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It s hard to understand what means "Shiny seems not to use the contents"

See example ( -- I have object "y" in my data.)

## UI

```
shinyUI(

  fluidPage(    
    shinyFilesButton('file', 'Load Dataset', 'Please select a dataset', FALSE),
    textOutput("txt")

  )
)
```

## Server

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  shinyFileChoose(input,'file', session=session,roots=c(wd='.'))

  observeEvent(input$file, {
    inFile <- parseFilePaths(roots=c(wd='.'), input$file)
    load(as.character(inFile$datapath), envir=.GlobalEnv)
    })

  output$txt=renderPrint({
  input$file
  if(exists("y")) y})

  })
```

Text changed from data.

for simplisity you can use `reactiveValues` like

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  shinyFileChoose(input,'file', session=session,roots=c(wd='.'))
  envv=reactiveValues(y=NULL)
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    inFile <- parseFilePaths(roots=c(wd='.'), input$file)
    load(as.character(inFile$datapath))
    envv$y=y
    })

  output$txt=renderPrint({envv$y})

  })
```

Both variants work but second better if you need different data in sessions.

Comment: When I want to select a file from the client computer, I only have access to the server files?!! how can I choose files/folders from the client computer?

Comment: @mohammad if you want file from client pc , you can usr fileinput https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html