# shinyFiles library not working with "read.csv"

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to play with shinyFiles library and while I figured out the UI part of the shinyFiles, I can't get the server part working. Here is my code so far

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(
    'Selections with shinyFiles',
    'shinyFiles example'
  ),
  sidebarPanel(
    shinyFilesButton('file', 'File select', 'Please select a file', FALSE)
    ),
  mainPanel(
    tags$h4('The output of a file selection'),
    tableOutput("contents")
    )
    ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  shinyFileChoose(input, 'file', roots=c(wd='/home/rstudio'), filetypes=c('', 'csv'))
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    df <- read.csv(input$file)
    print(head(df))
  })
})

runApp(list(
  ui=ui,
  server=server
))
```

This is the error that I am getting

```
Warning: Error in read.table: 'file' must be a character string or connection
```

I just want to make the server side to print the header of the file that I chose with shinyFilesButton. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619989/loading-data-files-with-shinyfiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `parseFilePaths` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyFiles/versions/0.3.2/topics/parseFilePaths in order to get parse the file name. Then `$datapath` should be used to get the file name.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(
    'Selections with shinyFiles',
    'shinyFiles example'
  ),
  sidebarPanel(
    shinyFilesButton('file', 'File select', 'Please select a file', FALSE)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tags$h4('The output of a file selection'),
    tableOutput("contents")
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  shinyFileChoose(input, 'file', roots=c(wd='.'), filetypes=c('', 'csv'))
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    inFile <- parseFilePaths(roots=c(wd='.'), input$file)
    if( NROW(inFile)) {
      df <- read.csv(as.character(inFile$datapath))
      print(head(df))
    }
  })
})

runApp(list(
  ui=ui,
  server=server
))
```

Note: I changed the root path in the above code to allow it to run on my system.

This is related to: [Loading data files with ShinyFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619989/loading-data-files-with-shinyfiles)

Comment: Thank you Scott. That works like a charm. I get the output that I wanted but what is this error I see when I open the shiny app indicate `invalid 'description' argument`?

Comment: Your welcome. The error is showing because no file is selected, check if there is a file by checking the number of rows in `inFile`. I'll update my answer.